# Exception: Duplicate entry '1-\x01' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity called `newEntity1` in an embedable class `Leaverequest`. I am using `Collectionofelements` in the entity class but I am getting the following exception. Could anyone please explain what it means?

**Exception**

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1-\x01' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-\x01' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**Entity:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.treamis.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements;

/**
 *
 * @author hyva
 */
@Entity
public class NewEntity1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @CollectionOfElements
    private Set<LeaveAppliedDetails> leaveAppliedDetails = new LinkedHashSet<LeaveAppliedDetails>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.treamis.entity.NewEntity1[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    public Set<LeaveAppliedDetails> getLeaveAppliedDetails() {
        return leaveAppliedDetails;
    }

    public void setLeaveAppliedDetails(Set<LeaveAppliedDetails> leaveAppliedDetails) {
        this.leaveAppliedDetails = leaveAppliedDetails;
    }

    public boolean addLeaveAppliedDetails(LeaveAppliedDetails e) {
        return leaveAppliedDetails.add(e);
    }

}
```

**Tester Class:**

```
NewEntity1 newEntity = new NewEntity1();

LeaveAppliedDetails lad=new LeaveAppliedDetails();
lad.setHalfDay(true);
newEntity.addLeaveAppliedDetails(lad);
LeaveAppliedDetails lad1=new LeaveAppliedDetails();
lad1.setHalfDay(true);
newEntity.addLeaveAppliedDetails(lad1);
Session s=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
s.save(newEntity);
s.beginTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: You should provide code for LeaveAppliedDetails as well. I guess the problem is caused when saving those entities.

Answer (score 0):

[In these docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues) you can read the following:

> **Note**
>
> We recommend you to migrate from
>   @org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements to the new
>   @ElementCollection annotation.

I would recommend you to change the annotation `@CollectionOfElements` to `@ElementCollection` and then go step by step through the above section.

I think the problem is, that you try to add new objects of `LeaveAppliedDetails`, which don't exist in the database yet (no primary key is known), to your `NewEntity1` class. So try to save & retrieve the new `LeaveAppliedDetails` objects before adding them to `NewEntity1`.